# How to anchor the first <h3> element of jQuery Accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using jQuery Accordion with 6 `<h3>` headers and several `<div>` sub elements. When I open all the sections and then close them again. The accordion ends up about 100px lower down the page.

**Is there a way to anchor the first `<h3>` so that the Accordion always ends up closed in the same place?**

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? This seems like an odd problem, I'd like to see it in action.

Comment: Please provide code and/or [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The problem seems to be caused from something in your css. Try to isolate it by putting only the accordion in a new page to check if you still get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it. The 'top' and 'left' parameters give the position of the accordion specific to my page.

```
#accordion:first-child
{
position: absolute;
top:51px;
left:8px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, give it an absolute or fixed position

```
h3{
 position: absolute;
 }
```

or

```
h3{
 position: fixed;
 }
```